# C programming local character pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, malloc

I have a function that returns the first n characters until a specified character is reached. I want to pass a ptr to be set to the next word in the string; how do I accomplish this? Here is my current code.

```
char* extract_word(char* ptrToNext, char* line, char parseChar)
// gets a substring from line till a space is found
// POST: word is returned as the first n characters read until parseChar occurs in line
//      FCTVAL == a ptr to the next word in line
{
   int i = 0;
   while(line[i] != parseChar && line[i] != '\0' && line[i] != '\n')
   {
      i++;
   }

   printf("line + i + 1: %c\n", *(line + i + 1));  //testing and debugging

   ptrToNext = (line + i + 1);    // HELP ME WITH THIS! I know when the function returns
                                  //   ptrToNext will have a garbage value because local
                                  //   variables are declared on the stack

   char* temp = malloc(i + 1);

   for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
   {
      temp[j] = line[j];
   }
   temp[i+1] = '\0';

   char* word = strdup(temp);
   return word;
}
```

Comment: `word` resides on stack but not the data pointed by the `word`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd pass an argument that is a *pointer to pointer to char*; then in the function, you can change the value of the pointed-to pointer. In other words

```
char * line = ...;
char * next;
char * word = extract_word(&next, line, 'q');
```

And inside your function...

```
// Note that "*" -- we're dereferencing ptrToNext so
// we set the value of the pointed-to pointer.
*ptrToNext = (line + i + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are library functions to help you strspn() strcspn() come in very handy for this kind of problem.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *getword(char *src, char parsechar)
{

char *result;
size_t len;
char needle[3] = "\n\n" ;

needle[1] = parsechar;
len = strcspn(src, needle);

result = malloc (1+len);
if (! result) return NULL;
memcpy(result, str, len);
result[len] = 0;
return result;
}
```